# VS Code error "Cannot convert undefined or null to object" on all JavaScript files

Tags: javascript, visual-studio-code

Just this week, whenever I use VS Code to open any JavaScript file, I get a popup at the top of the screen with the indicated error message. It doesn't seem to matter what is in the JS file, and this is a new behavior. It also triggers on js files I didn't write, such as mongoose.js, or any other .js file.

This error does not appear on other types of files, such as HTML or CSS.

I've tried uninstalling and reinstalling VS Code, but that didn't fix the issue.

Has anyone else encountered this? How to I fix or disable this error message? It is very annoying.

Comment: Hmm have you tried uninstalling and reinstalling? Mine is working fine.

Comment: Yes, that was the first thing I tried, but it didn't solve the issue.

Comment: Most probably the error is in one of configuration / template files. You can try 1) login as different user and check if there is the error, 2) Go to [currentUser]\appdata\Local\microsoft\visualstudio and cleanup some.

Comment: I figured it out. It came from me setting the built-in terminal to work with powershell instead of the standard command prompt. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Answering my own question since I just got an alert that it was getting a lot of views:

Per my comment above, the problem was being caused by setting the built-in terminal to work with Powershell instead of the standard Windows CLI.